# One word noun for "truth-teller"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a single word to describe people with a lack of honesty: *liar*. Is there an equivalent single word to describe an honest person?

The word must be a noun and not an adjective. The are obviously many adjectives that describe people who tell the truth. I am looking for something somewhat like the Spanish word, *verdadero*.

Comment: Unimaginative? ;o)

Comment: So, not 'truth-teller' itself?   1913 Webster : "One who tells the truth."

Comment: @jgbelacqua I don't realy qualify that as a single word. Just like I don't consider *speaker-of-that-which-is-not-false* a single word.

Comment: @Peter: How about X-Ray? Hyphens in words do not make them not words. How are you choosing which is which?

Comment: @MrHen *Truth-teller* is a compound of two morphologically independent words. X-Ray is a compound of one word and one letter that does not have independent meaning. Same thing with e-mail.

Comment: @Peter: So why bother with the hyphen? Just for clarity?

Comment: @MrHen I don't know. Maybe convention, maybe simply to make people understand that it is pronounced /ɛksɹe/ and not /zɹe/.

Comment: This seems like an artificial distinction to me.

Comment: I had never until this day seen or heard the word "truth-teller".  I suspect that it fell out of common usage sometime after 1913.

Comment: @intuited  Check the twitter feed usage for "truth-teller" on wordnik, for instance.  I'll add a few more here.

Comment: From the sitcom Drake and Josh - Drake: "Are you calling me a liar?" Josh: "Well I ain't calling you a **truther**!".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a word, the answer is "no". In the same way there is no direct antonym for murderer, thief, car-jacker, etc.

Saying that, there *did* use to be a word: [Soothsayer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=soothsayer). (In the mid-14th century it meant, "one who speaks truth".)

Comment: Yep, "soothsayer" was on the tip of my tongue.  Unrelated guitar geekery: So how are the fingers holding up?

Comment: They still haven't grown back ;-)

Comment: Could the opposite of _murderer_ be _necromancer_? _Thief_; _interior-decorator_ or _mover_? _Car-jacker_ would be _auto salesman_? A little creativity can find some useful terms. But yeah, no strict antonym is there. It is sort of like asking for the opposite of 4 or the letter H.

Comment: +1 for soothsayer; I didn't know that was what it originally meant.

Comment: Note that per the etymonline chronology (mid-14th century vs. late 14th century), *soothsayer* had just a few decades of literal use before it acquired the modern figurative meaning. In fact, I suspect it always had the figurative meaning, and it just lost the literal one fairly early on. See http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED41702

Comment: Okay, but that's because "murder" and "theft" do not have an opposite in the way that truth is a direct opposite to falsehood. And, as Peter notes, Spanish has `verdarero`.

Answer (score 10):

*Straight-shooter* comes to mind.

Comment: That's fairly colloquial though and I personally would answer 'No' to the OP's question.

Comment: @acron It may be colloquial, but doesn't "liar" itself have more colloquial uses than technical ones?

Comment: Pretty good answer!

Answer (score 8):

I cannot think of a simple antonym for liar. [This thread](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-314188.html) postulates that this is because there is no absolute condition for truth.

Idealistically, one assumes that another is always telling the truth, and if he is not telling the truth he becomes a liar. In essence, we may prescribe that telling the truth is a "normal" behavior and thus a word has not been given to describe it. Similarly, there are no simple antonyms for killer or robber.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. You might as well ask what's the word for a person who doesn't have leprosy, or who isn't the President of the United States.

Comment: It could also simply be because veracity is necessarily the default/dominant mode of expression.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think those are quite a bit different - "President of the United States" is not one word in itself. For "leper", we can imagine a world full of lepers, and so there would be a word for non-leper. (I wouldn't be surprised if there is an historical one.) Truth is different - if we try to imagine a world where the default mode of expression is lying, that is merely a change in _language_ - we've swapped the meaning of true and false - and not a change in the world. This is why I said it is _necessarily_ the default mode. (I believe this observation first came from Quine.)

Comment: @Hal @FumbleFingers I might have agreed, but it would seem that the lack of a word for *truth-teller* would be more universal linguistically if it was comparable to the lack of an antonym for *killer*. That is, if the word would be so uncommon, why do so many other languages have it?

Comment: @Peter The example you provided in your question, _verdadero_, is an adjective. For that, English has many equivalents - honest, real, truthful. Do you have other examples? Or an example of _verdadero_ used as a noun?

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig I once read about a language (a constructed one) where lying was the default and assumed mode of expression. It was an interesting thought experiment to think about the sort of conversations that would come out of it. I can't seem to find it at the moment, but there were dialogues like, "Would you like a cup of coffee?" "Oh no, I despise the taste of coffee." "Do you want it with or without cream and sugar?" "I want it without. I prefer my coffee black." "I don't like cream and sugar either."

Comment: @HaL In Spanish, all (or nearly all) adjectives, depending on how they are placed in the sentence, can be nouns. For example, "Los jovenes quieren comer" ("The young [ones] want to eat") or "Me prefiero los verdaderos sobre los guapos" ("I prefer the honest [ones] over the handsome [ones]).

Comment: @Peter: Quine's (I hope, or someone else's) point is that that thought experiment doesn't work. If we encountered that language and tried to construct a translation for it, we wouldn't translate the sentence as "I despise coffee"[lying], we'd translate it as "I love coffee". It's not a language where everyone lies; it's a language where "despise" means "adore" and "without" means "with", and vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

In logic puzzles about people who always lie and people who always tell the truth (of which there are many), the latter are usually called *truth-tellers*. However, sometimes one finds in that context *truthers*, a word that has since come to mean [something else](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truther) also.

Comment: Indeed, it was a logic puzzle of that class which made me search the internet for "antonym of liar", which lead me here.

Answer (score 4):

**Candid**? As in: "He's a perfectly candid fellow; he told the Emperor exactly what he thought of his new wardrobe."  **Frank** would also work there.

Comment: Being truthful doesn't necessarily mean you volunteer information that is not constructive.

Comment: @mmyers Where on earth is "volunteering information that is not constructive" in the definition of candid?

Comment: That's one part of how I take both "candid" and the roughly synonymous "blunt". Some people would say "I don't like your shirt" and then call themselves honest for saying what they think. That's truthful but not useful. On further research, however, it appears that this is not a common definition for either candid or blunt, so I retract my first comment.

Comment: Neither "candid" nor "frank" are nouns as the original asker required, but +1 for effort.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. A person can be characterized as being a "truth teller" or an "honest broker," a "reputable source" who is "believable" and possesses "veracity." There appears to be no single noun - in common use, anyway - that captures the idea.

Adjectively, however, we have many choices. A person can be genuine, straight forward, sincere, frank, honorable, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fine to use *truth-teller* itself.

The first rule of philosophical discussion (and from the comments, we are having a philosophical discussion) is to define your terms.

Our quodlibet here is not "that which has not yet been named," but the *liar* to which we are proposing an opposite.

There is not a simple sense of a liar which is has a unanimous, agreed upon meaning in all circumstances.   In this case, determining an antonym becomes difficult.

A liar is someone who has told a lie.
A liar is a person who has habitually told lies.
A liar is a person who usually tells lies.
A liar is a person who can't tell the truth.
A liar is a person who can't tell the truth in particular "important" contexts.
A liar is someone who has told a lie in a particular, "important" context (priestly initiation, marriage, job interview).
A liar is someone who has told a lie that is known to be a lie.
A liar is someone who has told a lie, whether the subject of the lie is a justified belief on the part of the liar or not.
A two-year-old, with developing cognitive and moral abilities, is a liar whether by "intent" or "accident".
A liar is someone who has told a lie, whether by intent or accident.
A liar is someone who has told a lie, whether by omitting the full truth or deliberately obscuring it.
A liar is anyone who has said anything "defininitive" except for the most trivial of statements, given the messy way that human brains deal with propositions, conflicting desires and loyalities, and the overloaded meanings that things in the real world have.
A liar is a robot with a broken truth-telling module.
A liar is someone who tells lies to me, repeatedly, during the period of our acquaintence.
A liar is a person who tells "little white lies" .
A liar is a person who tells "little white lies" habitually, with an occasional targeted lie to their significant other, employer.
A liar is a person who tells their lover, spouse, significant other, "I love you," without really knowing whether they mean it, on at least one day a month.
A liar is a person if their Diety has determined them to be a liar, according to The Rules.
A liar is the opposite of a whistle-blower, whether by actively covering up the truth of some circumstance, event, or condition, or by failing to communicate it to those who might be affected.

What's the opposite of a "liar"?

As a single answer, a flexible word is about the only thing that can work here.  That, or multiple words for different antonymic senses.

Why not *truth-teller*?

I'm deriving some of this from my earlier comments and discussion around them.

My initial definition of *truth-teller* from the 1913 edition of Webster's was "One who tells the truth."

The two criticisms I've seen are that the term isn't contemporary, or that it's not a "single word".

I believe that it is certainly in current usage.  (Certainly more so than *soothsayer*, even though *soothsayer* can also mean "truth-teller".)

Here are some usage examples from print:

[Larry Summers: a Truth-Teller ...](http://www.boston.com/bostonglobe/editorial_opinion/editorials/articles/2011/03/09/summers_a_truth_teller_and_not_just_to_winklevi/)

> [...] there’s something refreshing about
>   his persona as a truth-telling
>   curmudgeon who’s equally honest about
>   himself.

[Punishing the Truth-Tellers](http://www.consortiumnews.com/2011/031511.html)

Ironic usage:
[The Washington Post, “Bill Kellers wrongheaded attack on HuffPo”](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/plum-line/2011/03/bill_kellers_wrongheaded_attac.html)

> Indeed, just yesterday, HuffPo
>   prominently linked to a great Times
>   story debunking many of the claims of
>   bold truth-teller Chris Christie.

[Helene Cooper, *The House at Sugar Beach*](http://books.simonandschuster.com/9781416565727)

> I would then return to Liberia a conquering hero, a famous journalist, a truth-teller extraordinaire.

[Mark Clark Review of *State of Play*](http://www.obsessedwithfilm.com/reviews/mark-reviews-state-of-play-possibly-the-last-of-its-kind.php)

> "If there’s a hard sell in our day to day lives it’s the concept of the heroic journalist, the character State of Play director Kevin MacDonald calls his ‘truth-teller’.

There are more examples from twitter, from google books, from titles on Amazon, etc..

The accepted answer, *soothsayer* is as much a compound as *truth-teller* is. It also has the sense of 'fotune--teller' -- someone who can divine the truth, not necessarily someone who speaks truth consistently.  This may be the sense intended by the OP, but isn't what I would consider the opposite of a liar.

*Straight-shooter* (from @Kevin) is another nice compound, which has in some cases overlapping meaning with some cases of *truth-teller*.

As @msh210 points out, *truth-teller* has had a technical usage in logic puzzles for a long time -- simply meaning "someone who always tells the truth," as opposed to the liar, who always lies (or gives *not p* when the truth is *p*).

But in common parlance, the word *truth-teller* usually means someone who speaks the truth in difficult circumstance, or tells "truths" which are widely unpopular (within some related constituency).

Comment: I don't deny that "truth-teller" is used contemporarily with the meaning I want, and I agree that soothsayer is no longer used in its literal sense anymore. I still maintain that "truth-teller" is not a single word, unless you can arbitrarily combine any combination of words and put hyphens between them and call it a single word, like *speaker-of-that-which-is-not-false*. I'll give you +1 anyways, though.

Comment: @Peter I'll let an expert an compound words deal with the compound word vs multi-word vs whatever issue, if there is one hereabouts.   But I think your contrived example is contrived.  (I kid!)   There are better ones, but I can't really argue the point if single word is defined as "a word without hyphens".

Answer (score 1):

Adjective, not a noun, but *unimpeachable*?

Answer (score 1):

Adjective, not a noun, but Honest.

Comment: Also *trustworthy*.

Comment: These are good and could be used as substantives in certain context.

Answer (score 1):

**Blunt** and **undiplomatic** are words that can be used when the truth is not exactly a welcome thing. **Candid** is similar but less so.

Comment: But those are adjectives, like "honest".

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few negative ones: rat, fink, snitch, mole, loose cannon, tattletale, traitor, blabbermouth.

A not so negative one: critic.  "He was my friend and critic" means he didn't lie about things to make me feel good.

Someone who gives information: informer, informant. (This is presumed true, otherwise he or she is a misinformer, not an informer.)

It's all about what/whose truth you tell to whom, in what role.

Also: reporter. (A reporter gives a truthful, if subjective, account; a lie is not a report.)

Announcer.

Inspector. (Determines the truth of a situation, and relays.)

The word "witness" sometimes implies telling the truth. A witness can lie, but is then "bearing false witness" or may be a "hostile witness". In the absence of these situations, a witness is presumed to be telling the truth. Another use of the word: Jehovah's Witnesses believe they are spreading the truth, which is probably part of the reason why they chose that name for themselves.

A voice that tells a story: narrator. A narrative may be fictional, but that isn't the same thing as a lie. A narrator for a documentary or true story is a truth-teller.

Advisor.

Confidant. More like someone who guards the truth, but it goes hand in hand with honesty. Someone who lies to you is probably not suitable for a confidant/e!

Intimate (noun).

Comment: For 'finch' did you mean 'fink'?

Comment: Yes I didi! Finch is a bird.

Answer (score 1):

Try also *blunt speaker, plain speaker, forthright person, outspoken person, someone who tells it like it is, someone who calls it like he sees it.*

There is also *honest broker* (used of someone acting as an intermediary).

Incidentally, what's the deal with so many people wanting one-word descriptors for what are often quite complex or significantly context-bound concepts? Multi-word nouns exist for good reason.

Answer (score -1):

No, there won't be a word to mean truth-teller. Or a perfect antonym of *liar*.

One is expected to speak the truth, by default. When everyone is supposed to be honest, a liar is an exception.

Only when liars become the predominent majority do we need to coin a word/ neologism for the honest.

Comment: That view is based on some pretty unrealistic assumptions about how the world actually works. If a particular person always told the truth about everything, they would quickly develop a terrible reputation for being boorish, insensitive, bullying, rude, and generally unpleasant to deal with.

Comment: @ErikKowal We are almost there -- tells a lot about Man's "development." It's to do with cultural anthropology, though, not language, which we are dealing with here.

Comment: @ErikKowal http://english.stackexchange.com/a/19573/14666 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/19561/14666 -- It's just that I came in late, saw the question a full three weeks after it was posted. Others had said essentially the same thing already.