# What's a word for someone dedicated to the truth?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For example:

> He never held the truth from us, he is a _____.

I know there are plenty of adjectives to describe this type of person, but I'm looking for more of a noun like a "*warrior or advocate of truth*" if there is such a word.

Comment: You could call somebody a *truth-seeker*. Does this fit, or are you looking for something stronger?

Comment: It runs in the family. He never held the truth form us, he is a direct descendant of George Washington.

Comment: And I would add that you could probably use the phrase "advocate of truth" here and people would know exactly what you are saying, even if it isn't an established phrase.

Comment: *truth-teller*: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Truth-teller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One word noun for "truth-teller"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19556/one-word-noun-for-truth-teller)

Comment: He is a crusader ?

Comment: Not thinking of anything yet but I imagine there is something to be found in church history

Comment: Perhaps a lower case jesuit or tariqah

Answer (score 1):

"Honest" is too short to finish up your sentence, so let's do it like this:

> He never held the truth from us, he is *honest to a fault*.

This has the advantage that this guy takes honesty to an extreme.  But this is not a criticism.  It just means he doesn't have a dishonest or exaggerating hair on his body.

Answer (score 0):

"He always tells the truth, he is FRANK.

open, honest, and direct in speech or writing, especially when dealing with unpalatable matters.
"a long and frank discussion"

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about honesty in telling the truth, I'd go with "candid", which means

> saying what you think openly and honestly; not hiding your thoughts

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/candid

There are other synonyms of of course:

> frank, candid, open, plain mean showing willingness to tell what one
>   feels or thinks. frank stresses lack of shyness or secretiveness or of
>   evasiveness from considerations of tact or expedience . candid suggests expression marked by sincerity and
>   honesty especially in offering unwelcome criticism or opinion . open implies frankness but suggests more
>   indiscretion than frank and less earnestness than candid . plain suggests outspokenness and freedom from
>   affectation or subtlety in expression .

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/candid

Note, however, these words have to do mainly with being honest with others and telling your thoughts and feelings to them.  It's more of a concept about communication and relationship between people.  It is different from a philosopher or political activist who is in search of truth or vows to discover the truth about something.  In that case, a truth-seeker or any of your more descriptive terms seem to be more accurate.